# Flood Fill algorithm causes StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, flood-fill

I am programming a simple paint application using Java. I'm trying to use a recursive implementation of the Flood Fill algorithm as my 'bucket fill' tool.

However, this *always* gives me a `StackOverFlowError`. (No matter how small the area that I'm using the 'bucket fill tool' on is).

**EDIT: Changed the code to make it more efficient. Still same error.**

Here's the code:

```
public void floodFill(int x, int y, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor) throws AWTException{

    pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(x,y);

    g.setColor(replacementColor);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);

    if(robot.getPixelColor(x-1, y).equals(targetColor))
        floodFill(x-1, y, targetColor, replacementColor);

    if(robot.getPixelColor(x+1, y).equals(targetColor))
        floodFill(x+1, y, targetColor, replacementColor);

    if(robot.getPixelColor(x, y-1).equals(targetColor))
        floodFill(x, y-1, targetColor, replacementColor);

    if(robot.getPixelColor(x, y+1).equals(targetColor))
        floodFill(x, y+1, targetColor, replacementColor);

}
```

I would like to know if there is a **way to still use recursion** with this algorithm, and not get this error.

**If not**, what possible **non-recursive implementations** of this algorithm are there, that I can use in my program?

Comment: It looks like all this fancy manipulation of pixels doesn't do anything, since `fillRect` is only looking at `mouseLocation` anyway.

Comment: @Jyro117 What do you mean? Could you explain this again?

Comment: Well unless your target color equals your replacement color I can't see how it will terminate. Change your if statement to also check if pixelColor equals replacementColor

Comment: One (naive) solution would to increase stack size (`-Xss`). Another one (out of the scope) would be to replace recursion with iteration. You can improve the algorithm by checking whether the current pixel is inside the area being flooded. Also you can provide two-dimensional array containing visited pixels and comparing them with the current one. And the most important one: stackoverflow.com is NOT an error! ;-)

Comment: The current issue is because of your condition is missing a case: if(robot.getPixelColor(x-1, y).equals(targetColor) && !robot.getPixelColor(x-1, y).equals(replacementColor))

Comment: @Jyro117 saying that `pixel.equals(targetColor)` also means that `!pixel.equals(replacementColor)`. It's implicit, why should I add it?

Comment: Sorry, it appears I got myself confused. You are correct, I can't see anything else wrong with your implementation. This means the issue has to do with the color robot is getting and the graphics object you are drawing to are different.  Do you need to flush the graphics? Do you need to refresh the robot to get the current value?

Comment: You should always (and now in particular) post an [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think we'll be able to help until you do. Also, this probably won't be too difficult to figure out if you debug it.

Comment: Add your setColor, getPixelColor and fillRect function please.

Answer (score 1):

You additionally have to check for the already set target color, otherwise you overwrite the same target color again and again.

Comment: Right, misunderstood this.

Answer (score 1):

Just check at the **beginning of the function** the current Position, which color it has.

If it already has the replacementColor you already visited this point and can return.

```
public void floodFill(int x, int y, Color targetColor, Color replacementColor) throws AWTException{
{
  if(robot.getPixelColor(x, y).equals(replacementColor))
    return;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to implement bucket fill is to figure out which figure or area contains the mouse click position. (e.g) if you click inside a circle(with no other objects), then you want to fill up the circle. So if you maintain some kind of area map you can quickly figure out in which area the mouse click position is and fill up that area using existing methods (from some standard Java or external software) to fill up an area with colour.