# Java: How to color in a black and white map

Tags: java, graphics, weighted

I am working on trying to create a weighted and can't not figure out how to color it with out going pixel by pixel.

What I am aiming for is something like [image]

and what I currently have is [image]

My idea is to set up a table that will contain each zip code and a pixel. Then lets say I need zip code 63678 to be green. So I will tell the system to find that pixel and color it green along with every pixel around it until it hits all black. Much like how the fill bucket works in paint.

Is this a possibility or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I would first write a function that can fill an entire line with colour. Start at the pixel x,y position, then color (x-1,y), (x+1,y), then (x-2, y), (x+2, y) recursively. Stop either branch if the pixel at the x,y position is found to be black or the edge of the map is reached. Now, once you have this function you can write another function that colors lines in vertically. It will start at pixel x,y, then call the line fill function you wrote previously for (x, y-1), (x,y+1) then (x, y-2), (x, y+2) and so on. This should fill the whole area eventually.

Comment: you could use longitude and latitude as your x,y coords and create a function that translates the long, lat into the x,y that corresponds to all the zip codes...

Comment: mdewit: I like that idea. I think I will experiment with that.

Comment: RAZ: My problem isn't the location of each zip but what to do when I have that location.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [flood-fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) (like the "pouring paint-can" icon in Microsoft Paint).  (You can also [search for "flood-fill" and "java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flood-fill+java) on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase If you put your comment as an awnser I will accept it. This lead me to this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864019/flood-fill-algorithm-causes-stackoverflowerror after some searching. This helped me solve my issues with a little bit of tweaking. Thank you very much.